# Wix - How do I set property conditionally

Tags: wix

I'm trying to do is:

```
if registrySearch exist then
  set INSTALL_DIR to C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MySoftware
else
  set INSTALL_DIR to C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\Folder
```

Anyone know to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let say this the registry key you searched.

```
<Property Id="REGSEARCH">
    <RegistrySearch Id="TestReg"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="Software\TestKey\TestKey2"
             Name="Test"
                    Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

This is how to set the property conditionally.

Keep the default value as the value you need to put when the registry does not exist.

```
<Property Id="INSTALL_DIR" Value="C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\Folder" />
```

Then set the property value as follows if the registry exists.

```
<SetProperty Id="INSTALL_DIR" After="AppSearch" Value="C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MySoftware" Sequence="first" >
  <![CDATA[REGSEARCH]]>
</SetProperty>
```

Comment: I think there's a mistake: value of the `SetProperty` directive should be set with `Value="[REGSEARCH]"`, as per your example. The inner text in the `SetProperty` tag is just a conditional and I think it evaluates to true only when the `TestReg` search is successful, but the value set will be always the static string, not the registry found one.